# DocuSign Document loses styles when I use SignHereTabs using C# DocuSign SDK

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi, digital-signature

I am using DocuSign SDK for sending html documents for signing, when I send the document without specifying the position to sign, it works fine, all the css styles are applied and the document looks exactly as I wanted. but when I use the SignHere Tab to specify exactly where the signer should sign(see code), the document loses all it's styles and becomes one long document with only texts aligned left (even html tables are lost).

```cs
        SignHere signHere = new SignHere
        {
            DocumentId = "1",
            AnchorString = "Signature obligatoire",
            AnchorXOffset = "3",
            AnchorYOffset = "10",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels"
        };

        envelopeDefinition.Recipients = new Recipients
        {
            Signers = new List<Signer>()
            {
                new Signer
                {
                    Email = "test@test.com",
                    Name = "test",
                    RecipientId = "1",
                    RoutingOrder = "1",
                    Tabs = new Tabs
                    {
                        SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere },
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I tried disabling/enabling responsive signing, but it didn't work.

Edit :
also when I access the document from my account in docusign, the document looks fine

[desired document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G1Oy.png)

but when I want to sign it, it loses its styles:

[result when I want to sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9DR6.png)

Comment: Can you **edit** your question to include the API log (from DocuSign)? xxx out any private information.

Comment: @LarryK there is no logs, because it's not an error, the envelope is successfully sent to the user's email. it's just the styling of the page is lost.

Comment: There's always a log. See [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus)

Comment: @ayoub_dkhissi does it work correctly (looks like you want) when you do it from the web app, but not when you do it using C# code? If that's the case - it's easy and I can show you what to do. If not - then not sure it's possible, but may need to dig into this deeper.

Comment: @InbarGazit Yes I guess that's exactly the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of debugging and testing different approaches, I concluded that when I try to specify the position of the signature using SignHere tabs from C# code or the "ds-signature" tag in the HTML template, DocuSign somehow makes the document responsive and the the styles are lost.
However, when I used inline css it worked, the document still responsive, but at least the styles are not lost and the position of the signature is successfully spicified.

I guess DocuSign supports only inline css when using responsive signing.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to do something from API and it works from web app, all you need to do is log API calls and see what the web app does.

The Web app have a feature where you can log (up to 50) API calls and see exactly the calls that was made, with all the JSON information etc.

So you do that and see what you need.

Here is a video that explains how to log API calls - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw

Here is a blog post that explains how to log API calls -https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-how-to-use-api-logs